# Makefile для отдельных каталогов src и bin

Tags: g++, makefile

Существует дерево файлов:

```
folder
|-src
  |-myfile.cpp
  |-myfile.h
|-bin
|-Makefile
```

Хочу написать Makefile так, чтобы компилировались файлы, находящиеся в каталоге src, но объектные файлы создавались в текущем (в folder). А потом, чтобы они линковались в один файл в каталог bin.

На данный момент имею нерабочий Makefile. Ругается на отсутствие правила для myfile.o.

```
TARGET=myfile
OBJECTS=myfile.o
XX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11

all: ${TARGET}
${TARGET}: ${OBJECTS}
    ${XX} -o ${TARGET} ${OBJECTS}
.c.o:
    ${XX} ${CXXFLAGS} -c "${INCLUDE}$<" -o "$@"
```

Как правильно реализовать поставленную задачу?

Comment: попробуйте поместить в **пустой** каталог файлы `file.cpp` и `file.h`, и выполнить в этом каталоге `make CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11" file`.  возможно, результат вас поразит, и заставит подумать о том, что то, что вы задумали, в некотором смысле можно назвать «выдумыванием проблем на ровном месте».

Comment: *Ругается на отсутствие правила для myfile.o* — но его дейстивтельно нет. по крайней мере я его не вижу, так же как и программа make. объясните, пожалуйста, хотя бы словами, каким образом связаны между собою `myfile`, `myfile.o `, `file.cpp` и `file.h`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тут скорее эксперимент, а не выдумывание проблем. Я хочу оставить каталог с исходными файлами максимально нетронутым. Я понимаю, что можно сделать так, как вы показали. Но я же специально привёл простой пример, чтобы и объяснение могло быть простым. Меня интересует, как в Makefile указать отдельно откуда брать и куда кидать. Мне не надо просто сделать исполняемый файл. В вопросе всё написано.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin поправил названия. myfile.o получается при компиляции myfile.cpp. myfile.h - очевидно, заголовочный файл этого myfile.cpp. myfile - исполняемый файл, получаемый при линковке объектных файлов (в данном случае это только myfile.o).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> чтобы они линковались в один файл в каталог bin

значит, собирать вам надо не `myfile`, а `bin/myfile`. это я про переменную `TARGET`.

> объектные файлы создавались в текущем

так и укажите цель и пререквизиты соответствующим образом:

```
%.o: src/%.cpp
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

здесь вторая строка, рецепт, взята из [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html), которые можно посмотреть в выводе команды `make -p`

---

остаётся только объяснить компилятору, где искать заголовочный файл `myfile.h` (если, конечно, компилятор сам не «догадается»). тут я, как не-программист, вряд ли чем помогу. разве что предположу, что надо добавить к значению перменной `CPPFLAGS` или `CXXFLAGS` опцию `-I src`.

Comment: Работает, спасибо!

Comment: @AccumPlus: Тогда не забудьте отметить ответ зелёной птичкой (слева).

Comment: @AccumPlus: Ну, галочкой... :)

Answer (score 2):

Gnu make имеет интересную директиву [`vpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search), которая позволяет указать где искать те или иные исходники. В вашем случае достаточно добавить в начало Makefile:

```
vpath %.cpp src
vpath %.h src
CXXFLAGS+=-Isrc
```

И implicit rules тогда можно не переписывать.