# Ошибка в Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
DIR_BUILD=build/
DIR_SRC=src/
NAME_SOURCE=main.cpp http-server.cpp
SOURCES=$(foreach file, $(NAME_SOURCE), $(DIR_SRC)$(file))
OBJECTS=$(foreach object, $(NAME_SOURCE:.cpp=.o), $(DIR_BUILD)$(object))
EXECUTABLE=$(DIR_BUILD)wwwd

all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

print: $(SOURCES)
    echo '$(SOURCES)'

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

При выполнении данного Makefile выполняется следующее:

```
g++ -c -Wall src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
g++ -c -Wall src/main.cpp -o build/file.o
g++   build/main.o  build/file.o -o build/wwwd
```

Почему 2 раза компилируется `src/main.cpp`? (Переменная `SOURCES=src/main.cpp  src/file.cpp`)

Answer (score 1):

> Почему 2 раза компилируется `src/main.cpp`?

очевидный ответ: потому, что у вас именно так написано в мэйкфайле.

вероятно, вам требуется компилировать `build/main.o` из `src/main.cpp` и `build/http-server.o` из `src/http-server.o`.

если бы вы не занимались [напрасными усложнениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518983/178576), то последнего правила и не потребовалось бы. а так в нём, конечно, стоит изменить цель и пререквизиты. вместо:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
```

должно быть что-то вроде:

```
$(DIR_BUILD)/%.o: $(DIR_SRC)/%.cpp
```

тогда вы получите то, чего, вероятно, ожидаете:

```
$ make -n
g++ -c -Wall src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
g++ -c -Wall src/http-server.cpp -o build/http-server.o
g++   build/main.o  build/http-server.o -o build/wwwd
```

Answer (score 0):

правило

```
$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

не совсем корректно. Данное правило будет раскрыто как 2 правила

```
build/main.o: src/main.cpp src/file.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall src/main.cpp -o build/main.o
build/file.o: src/main.cpp src/file.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall src/main.cpp -o build/file.o
```

Физика процесса такова:

- $(OBJECTS): раскрываеться как 2 объектника, и Make система генерит по 1 правилу (таргету) для каждого из них. Тут все верно и ожидаемо.
- $< подставляет **первый** элемент из списка после двоеточия. Вот здесь и есть основная проблема, изза которой оба таргета компилируют один и тот же файл.

(то как Gnu Make раскрывает таргеты можно увидеть запустив 'make -np all > logfile')

Соответственно, чтобы исправить ситуацию нужно каждому таргету подставлять правильный исходник. Чтобы автоматизировать процесс советую применить трюк с правилом

```
%c: %o
    ...
```

Ниже - пример билд системы, которая сама подхватывает все исходники в заданых директориях.

Дервв файлов:

```
.                                                                                                                                                
|-- include                                                                                                                                      
|   `-- func.h                                                                                                                                   
|-- Makefile                                                                                                                                     
|-- src                                                                                                                                          
|   `-- func.c                                                                                                                                   
`-- src2                                                                                                                                         
    `-- prog.c
```

Makefile:

```
#Name of outpu binary (exe) file;                
PROGRAM_NAME := prog                             

# project dirs
export PROJECT_DIR := $(shell pwd)

export SRC_DIRS    := $(PROJECT_DIR)/src
export SRC_DIRS    += $(PROJECT_DIR)/src2

export INCLUDE_DIR := $(PROJECT_DIR)/include
export BUILD_DIR   := $(PROJECT_DIR)/build  
export OBJ_DIR     := $(BUILD_DIR)/obj      
export TARGET_DIR  := $(BUILD_DIR)/target   

# this meens that "checkbuilddirs" is not a file but rule to run
.PHONY: checkbuilddirs                                          

#list of source files (with whitespace between them)
SRC_FILES := $(foreach dirname, $(SRC_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dirname)/*.c))

#Object files
OBJ_FILES := $(foreach filename, $(notdir $(SRC_FILES)), $(OBJ_DIR)/$(filename:.c=.o))

# dependence dirs. VPATH is defined by gnu Make and used to look for any files if we use %
# It is like -I include dirs for compiller                                                
VPATH:=$(sort $(SRC_DIRS) $(foreach srcfile,$(SRC_FILES),$(dir $(srcfile))))              

# Include flags
LOCAL_INCLUDES:=$(foreach dirs, $(INCLUDE_DIR), -I$(dirs))

PROGRAM_FULL_NAME := $(TARGET_DIR)/$(PROGRAM_NAME)

# list of lib-flags for compiler. For example for math.h use    -lm
#LIB_FLAGS=-lm
CC:=gcc
CFLAGS:=-Wall $(LIB_FLAGS) $(LOCAL_INCLUDES)

# rule to build application
all: checkbuilddirs $(PROGRAM_FULL_NAME)

VERBOSE ?= false
ifeq ($(VERBOSE),true)
 QUIET  :=
else
 QUIET  := @
endif

#build executable file
$(PROGRAM_FULL_NAME): $(OBJ_FILES)
        @echo "Build program"
        $(QUIET)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

# build all object file
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
        @echo "Compile $(notdir $<)"
        $(QUIET)$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

#clean all
clean:
        $(QUIET)rm -f $(OBJ_FILES) $(PROGRAM_FULL_NAME)
        $(QUIET)rm -f $(BUILD_DIR) -r

checkbuilddirs: | $(BUILD_DIR) $(OBJ_DIR) $(TARGET_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
        $(QUIET)mkdir -p $@

$(OBJ_DIR):
        $(QUIET)mkdir -p $@

$(TARGET_DIR):
        $(QUIET)mkdir -p $@
```

Обратите внимание на сл. трюки:

- команда $(wildcard $(dirname)/*.c) сама найдет все файлы *.с в указаных директориях
- $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c - трактуется билд системой как универсальный таргет, который система применит для всех объектников. Обратите внимание, что исходный файл тут указан без указания папки.
- переменная VPATH - как было сказано выше, все исходники в dependency указаны без папок. VPATH - специальная переменная, используеться системой Make как список папок в которых можно искать исходники. Очень похоже на PATH, только для поиска исходников.

PS. пример проверен